# 'FlatMap can be used only with callable objects...'

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My code is attached.  There are two CSVs I need to read in.  I read in the first CSV, and then I want to pass that PCollection as a side input to the other CSV file I am going to read in line by line.  I then want to yield the two elements concatenated to the FlatMap function.  Probelm is, I can't get it to pass the data to the function (I'm using Python).  I have looked at plenty of examples online, others have done this in earlier versions. I know it's actually doing SOMETHING because I can at leastt write out the left csv to text file and can see it changed each line into a key value pair.  Would really appreciate some help here, thanks for reading.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import logging
import csv
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

class append_lr(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, lineup):
        self._lineup=(1,2)

    def process(self, left, right):
        bla=left
        burp=right
        both=left+right
        yield both


class MyCsvFileSource(beam.io.filebasedsource.FileBasedSource):
    def read_records(self, file_name, range_tracker):
        self._file = self.open_file(file_name)
        reader = csv.DictReader(self._file)
        for rec in reader:
            yield rec

def combine_lines():
    with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:

        left_side = p | 'Read_Left_Side' >> beam.io.Read(MyCsvFileSource('/folder/left_side.csv'))
        left_and_right = (p | 'Read_Rght_Side' >> beam.io.Read(MyCsvFileSource('/folder/right_side.csv'))
                     | beam.FlatMap(append_lr, beam.pvalue.AsIter(left_side)))
        left_and_right | 'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToText('/folder/', file_name_suffix='test_output.csv')

def run(argv=None):
    combine_lines()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run(None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was supposed to implement the DoFn as a "Callable" object, Apache Beam code doc snippet below says:

> ```
> def FlatMap(fn, *args, **kwargs):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
> ```
>
> """:func:`FlatMap` is like :class: `ParDo` except it takes a **callable** to specify the transformation.

So I changed the function from a class to def, worked like a charm.  A few other code changes as well that shows how to basically build a for-loop with side input from another PCollection (NOTE that if you run this locally, make sure your test files for left and right sides are fairly small, this produces huge sized outputs!):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import logging
import csv
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

class MyCsvFileSource(beam.io.filebasedsource.FileBasedSource):
    def read_records(self, file_name, range_tracker):
        self._file = self.open_file(file_name)
        reader = csv.DictReader(self._file)
        for rec in reader:
            yield rec

def append_lr(left_, right_):
    for thingy in right_:
        yield (left_, thingy)

def combine_sides():
    with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:
        left_file = '/path/to/file/left.csv'
        right_file = '/path/to/file/right.csv'
        test_output = '/path/to/file/outputs/'

        left_side = p | 'Read_Left_Side' >> beam.io.Read(MyCsvFileSource(left_file))
        right_side = p | 'Read_Right_Side' >> beam.io.Read(MyCsvFileSource(right_file))
        all_combos = left_side | beam.FlatMap(append_lr, beam.pvalue.AsIter(right_side))
        all_combos | 'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToText(test_output, file_name_suffix='purple_nurple.csv')

def run(argv=None):
    combine_sides()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run(None)
```